# Android Bitmap freeing memory - none of this works

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, bitmap, drawable

I get "bitmap size exceeds VM budget", eventually with my app. So I added all of these things to help alleviate the increasing memory footprint

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inTempStorage = new byte[32*1024];
        options.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode

        options.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared

        options.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future


        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

        Drawable pulled = BitmapDrawable.createFromResourceStream(null, null, conn.getInputStream(), "galleryImage", options);
```

I am also using weakhashmaps, recycling, System.gc()

and all this successfully PROLONGES the crash. where a device with a 32M heap initially would have only been able to handle a few images before crashing, now it can handle a dozen, but this doesn't fix the problem. The problem is the BitMap method is leaking memory and simply will not clear.

How do I fix this? The images are of size 256x357

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use `drawable.setCallback(null);` when you don't need a drawable anymore, because even if you're using a WeakHashMap, they can still be attached to the context through their callback attribute.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to really make sure those `Bitmaps` are freed, you have to call `recycle()` on those `Bitmaps` that are no longer needed. If you need all of them, then recycle least recently used ones (and re-load them, again when needed).

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with ImageView and i solved the memory problem using imageView.clearAnimation(); before to assign the new bitmap and now i have no memory error.