# Why bitmaps not destroy?

Tags: android

Whenever we create bitmaps objects,

- why they are not release by **System.gc();**.
- what is the best way to remove bitmap object

Answer (score 0):

The bitmaps are kind of tricky, if you want to clear the used memory. I use bitmap.recycle(), it empties the heap, but not quite so. This is asked before. You can see this for more info: [Android - Bitmap and memory management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996655/android-bitmap-and-memory-management) and this:[Android Bitmap freeing memory - none of this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460410/android-bitmap-freeing-memory-none-of-this-works)

Answer (score 0):

```
bitmap.recycle()
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823799/android-bitmap-recycle-how-does-it-work) link for further explanation.
For decoding larger image check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966).